# How to only substitute lines that match several patterns in sed?

Tags: sed

```
$ echo -e 'CH12\nCH23au' | sed '/^CH/s=^=<b>='
<b>CH12
<b>CH23au
```

I know I can match lines starting with `CH` by `^CH` but how can I match multiple patterns?

Example:

**Input:**

```
CH12
CH23au
```

**Output:**

```
CH12
<b>CH23au
```

How to only put `<b>` where there is `^CH` and `au` in the line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the `CH` must occur at the beginning of the line, the order of `CH` and `au` is fixed, so you can look for `^CH.*au`.

```
$ echo -e 'CH12\nCH23au' | sed '/^CH.*au/s=^=<b>='
CH12
<b>CH23au
$
```

If the order of the two patterns is not fixed, one could do something like

```
sed -e '/pattern1/{;/pattern2/s/old/new/;}'
```

but the perl solution

```
perl -pe 'if (/pattern1/ && /pattern2/) {s/old/new/;}'
```

is probably more readable.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach:

```
sed -e '/^CH/!b' -e '/au/!b' -e 's/^/<b>/'
```

`b` (branch to the end if not given any label argument) is like `continue` or `next` in other languages. So the above is like:

```
for (; line = readline(); print line) { # The implicit loop in sed
  if (!/^CH/) continue;
  if (!/au/) continue;
  line =~ s/^/<b>/
}
```